# C# HTTPS Parse Json

Tags: c#, json, парсер, https, json.net

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (
Object obj, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
    return (true);
};

var url = "https://api.zp.ru/...................";
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

На последней строчке ошибка: System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.). В чем может быть проблема, ведь через браузер я могу посмотреть json, но не могу его загрузить?

Пробовал ещё так (та же ошибка):

```
try
        {
            var myRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://api.zp.ru/........................");
            myRequest.Method = "GET";
            myRequest.UserAgent = "WebRequestDemo";
            using (var theResponse = myRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                var dataStream = theResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                object objResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var myUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(objResponse.ToString());
                dataStream.Close();
                theResponse.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Comment: А что в `InnerException`?

Comment: @VladD в innerException: System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:InternalError): System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.

Comment: Хм, это не оно: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26658?

Comment: Или может быть вот это: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13998?

Comment: @VladD большое спасибо) помогла первая ссылка

Comment: Отлично! Рад, что решение нашлось!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: установить ModernHttpClient, добавить в references System.Net.Http

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
{
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ServiceEndPoints.GetShopUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, ServiceEndPoints.ShopsUrl);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = response.Content;
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Shop>(json);
            }

            return new Shop();
 }`
```